# Loading Navbar from Separate HTML File Not Working

Tags: jquery, html, css

After reading a couple of other posts on Stack Overflow, I decided to use the jQuery method of adding a navbar to `index.html` whose code is in `header.html`. However, the navbar is not showing up on `index.html`, and the console says that there is an "Access to XMLHttpRequest error". Could someone please tell me why this error is appearing?

Here is my HTML for index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head> 


    <link href="header+footer.css" rel = "stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="index.css" rel = "stylesheet" type="text/css" />

     <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title> The Novel Column - Book Reviews </title>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script> 

    <script> 
        $(function(){
        $("#includedContent").load("header.html"); 
        });
    </script> 

 </head> 


<body>


     <div id="includedContent"></div>
```

Here is my HTML for header.html:

```
<nav>
    <img class="logo" src="images/other/logo.jpg">

    <h1> <a href="index.html"> The Novel Column </a> </h1>

    <ul>

      <li> <a href="about.html"> About </a> </li>
    </ul>



</nav>
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: is your header file in the same folder as the file referencing it?

Comment: XMLHttpRequest Error will be solved when you run your code on a server.
Locally you can use XAMPP for the testing purpose.

Comment: How can someone possibly help when you haven't shared the exact error you are getting?

Comment: @ATomCalledStu It is.

Answer (score 0):

**You can simply include the jQuery.js and load the HTML file using**

> $("#DivContent").load("yourFile.html");

For example

```
<html> 
  <head> 
    <script src="jquery.js"></script> 
    <script> 
      $(function(){
       $("#DivContent").load("another_file.html"); 
      });
    </script> 
  </head> 

  <body> 
     <div id="DivContent"></div>
  </body> 
</html>
```

> ***Note:*** inside load() method, make sure you are writing the right path of your external file.
> XMLHttpRequest Error will be solved when you run your code on a server. Locally you can use XAMPP for the testing purpose

**There are some third-party methods available like this .**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <script src="http://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3data.js"></script>

 <body>

  <div w3-include-html="content.html"></div> 

  <script>
    w3IncludeHTML();
  </script>

 </body>
</html>
```

> **I hope, My Answer will help you to understand. Thanks**

Answer (score 0):

This is normal if you are not working on a localhost.
Try working on Apache or IIS servers.

here you can learn what the error is : [XmlHttpRequest error: Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3595515/xmlhttprequest-error-origin-null-is-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow-origin)